# moving on the last line of a function

Tags: c++, c++11

I have an object in a method.  The object is passed in by value, modified in the function, and then passed as a parameter to std::make_tuple, which is then immediately returned.

```
std::tuple<bool, X> func(X x)
{
    // Modify x
    // ...
    return std::make_tuple(true, x);
}
```

My question is, will x be moved when it is passed to std::make_tuple?  I know that it would be moved if I just returned it, but since I am passing it to a function, will it be moved into the function or do I need to wrap it in std::move?

Comment: Question to ask yourself: what should a statement like `return std::make_pair(x, x);` do with `x`?  How would you formalize rules in the standard language to make that example and automatically moving from lvalues in arbitrary return-statement expressions work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> will x be moved when it is passed to std::make_tuple?

No, it will not be moved, because it is an **lvalue**. There is a situation where lvalues can be treated as rvalues when returning them from a function, but not in your example - see paragraph 12.8/32 of the C++11 Standard.

If you want `x` to be moved from, you have to explicitly say:

```
return std::make_tuple(true, std::move(x));
```

Answer (score 0):

No, you need to move it explicitly:

```
return std::make_tuple(true, std::move(x));
```

However, you might rather want `optional`*:

```
std::optional<X> func(X x)
{
    // modify x
    return std::move(x);
}
```

The allows constructing the optional object by move, so this is as "movy" as you get.

*) `optional` will be in the C++ standard in the future; in the meantime, `boost::optional` serves the same purpose.

Comment: @Andy: Isn't it that function parameters are also not moved implicitly?

Comment: Do you need the `move` in the `optional` case, as we are directly returning `x`?

Comment: @Yakk: It is needed. `x` is an lvalue, and it will be treated as an rvalue only when the return type of the function is exactly the same as the type of `x` (see `12.8p32`). This is not the case, since the return type is `optional<X>` instead of `X`.

Comment: @Yakk: I think so. Function parameters aren't moved, if I understand the argument correctly, and in any case your return type isn't `X`.

Comment: @Kerrek: Function parameters can be moved, although copy elision cannot be performed

Comment: @AndyProwl: Oh, right, I didn't read on -- that's in sentence 32 :-) Thanks

Comment: The x is not moved into the return value if is not an exact match on type?  Huh. What if you `{}`ed?